# How to send custom error message from the LoginController to the frontend?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I added a check in `LoginController` to limit the user's max number of connected devices.

I added the following in the `login()` method in the `LoginController`:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    // ... some code ...

    if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        if ($user->max_devices >= 5) {
            // if I dd() instead of returning this, it gets here
            return $this->sendMaxConnectedDevicesResponse($request);
        }
    }

    // ... some code ...
}

protected function sendMaxConnectedDevicesResponse(Request $request)
{
    throw ValidationException::withMessage([$this->username() => ['Device limit reached'])->status(403);
}
```

`sendMaxConnectedDevicesResponse` is a copy of `sendLockoutResponse` with my custom message, however I get warning that I have an unhandled exception (`Unhandled \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException`).

So how can I handle it like `sendLockoutResponse` handles it, so it will show as an error in the frontend, instead of just ignoring it? Right now, what happens is that even though it throws the error, it doesn't show it in the frontend, and it continues to log in as usual

I just didn't find a way to throw and catch the custom error properly

Answer (score 0):

In one of my projects, I've used this

```
throw ValidationException::withMessages([
    'key' => 'error message',
]);
```

---

In yours, you can use

```
throw ValidationException::withMessages([
    'device_limit' => 'Device limit reached',
]);
```

So in the frontend, you can get the error with the key `device_limit.`

---

In your login controller

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        if ($user->max_devices >= 5) {
            // Logout the user right after login
            $this->guard()->logout();

            // Throw an instance of HttpResponseException
            throw new HttpResponseException(
                response()->json(['error' => 'Device limit reached'], 403)
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it just continues to log in instead of stopping the login process

Comment: If  you need to prevent it from login you need to do the validation before it logged in

Comment: try the above code and see. `authenticated()` method get called automatically